# What is the relationship between speed and torque in a separately excited DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor

When a DC motor is powered by an external voltage source, as opposed to using shunt, series or compound configuration, how does speed relate to torque?

Comment: the current drawn is proportional to torque.  the *"back-emf"* (i don't recall the correct term for this) is proportional to the rotor speed and both are proportional to the stator current.

Answer (score 1):

- No load speed is linear with Voltage
- Torque is somewhat linear with current above excitation currents.
- Since stall current is 8~10x rated load current, speed will reduce as load - increases to rated current by more than 10% beyond this exceeds the rated current with conduction losses dominating thermal rise.
- This assumes driver and power supply ESR is much lower than DCR of motor coils which is not often the case so speed drops much more than 10%.
- since max power transfer occurs when load matches available electro-mechanical power, this max power occurs at half speed

  - but this may exceed the thermal rating of the motor.
- torque declines with rising speed due to back EMF.

  [image]

Comment: but what about excitation current to the magnet?

Comment: Series/shunt rotor/stator coil motors require more excitation current like transformers (10%) than those with permanent magnets as the magnets are already energized. So this is lower and can be neglected like stall speed and start voltage,, there is some effect but your question is unrelated to this... i.e. load torque vs RPM  at full voltage  ( if I understand your unstated assumptions)